# Android O new TextToSpeech onRangeStart() callback

Tags: android, text-to-speech

The new callback function onRangeStart() of TTS UtteranceProgressListener would let us e.g. highlight individual words of a longer phrase, as it's spoken by the TTS engine. The callback is defined in Android API reference at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html#onRangeStart(java.lang.String, int, int, int), but I cannot find anywhere the information on how to actually define the ranges in the phrase, when an app sends the phrase (e.g. a sentence) to the TTS engine for speech generation.

What are these "ranges" exactly and how they can be defined? Or are they pre-defined as "words" or anything separated with white space?

**More info:** I used the Android O emulator and created onRangeStart() callback in my TTS app, used different voices from Google TTS set to see if any ranges were defined automatically and the callback will be called. Nothing. Maybe the ranges must be defined somehow in the "params" Bundle of the speak() call???

Comment: I also reported the issue of lack of documentation for defining ranges for word-level highlighting to Google issue tracker, see my report there and their response: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62484359

Comment: Right now with Android 8 Oreo release, when using the English TTS voice from Google TTS product, I do get callbacks in onRangeStart() for each word spoken. Finally I'll be able to implement spoken word highlight in my TTS app!

Comment: Is this in the support libraries for APIs previous than 26?

Comment: I did not see it added to any support libraries so far. If you learn more about it, please share. Maybe it would be worth also to post feedback to Google to provide this function in older Androids via a support library.

Comment: Thanks for the info, ...hmmm, I'm going to search if there is a feature request of something related.

Answer (score 1):

Google is still not documenting this feature and the latest response to the [issue filed in their tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62484359) is "We've deferred this to a future release, but leaving this open for now."

Meantime by implementing onRangeStart() callback in my TTS app and make it show debug output, I see that that the "ranges" are simply words. I see this callback hit when using English voices from Google TTS only, no other TTS voices from Google or other companies that I tried so far, implement this yet. For example, reading aloud a sentence: "This is a sentence to read aloud." produces the following output in onRangeStart():

> ```
> onRangeStart(avar-1) start=0, end=4, frame=275         (This)
> onRangeStart(avar-1) start=5, end=7, frame=3575        (is)
> onRangeStart(avar-1) start=8, end=9, frame=6270        (a)
> onRangeStart(avar-1) start=10, end=18, frame=7810      (sentence)
> onRangeStart(avar-1) start=19, end=21, frame=18535     (to)
> onRangeStart(avar-1) start=22, end=26, frame=21285     (read)
> onRangeStart(avar-1) start=27, end=32, frame=25795     (aloud)
> ```

It would be helpful if someone from Google told us officially that "ranges" are simply words, at least for now.