# Text to speech, show read words

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am working on an android application to read text, but I need to display the text while it is reading.
I have already tried to add words to the TextToSpeech and display the word being read, as I show in the following code, but the fluency is not good when you order to read word by word compared to a complete sentence.

```
String[] list = {"My", "name", "is", "John"};
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                textView.append(" " + list[k++]);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        }
    });
```

... in the read order

```
for (String t: list){
    tts.speak(t, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, "ID");
}
```

So, what I need is to order reading a complete sentence and to display the words that are being read one by one.

Comment: It is not possible to highlight individual words in older versions. In newer version Android O there is `onRangeStart` callback for this purpose, but it is not yet functional, for details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461533/android-o-new-texttospeech-onrangestart-callback

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, thank you for your comment, I finally solved my problem, i synthesized each phrase in an audio file using the tts engine and obtained the duration of each file, then when reading each phrase with the tts engine I already knew the duration of each phrase to highlight the text using this library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6062. 
(sorry for my english).